# How long do I have to wait to hear back?

Tags: recruitment

I had two interviews for a director role and met : HR + Head Director + Brand Director.

Then the recruited did not get any feedback from the company as they were very busy before the xmas holidays.

I have contacted the HH more a week ago and they told to wait until this week , indeed and I haven't got any feedback indeed.

What shall I do? do I have to wait? Get in touch with the company's HR that I have met? Or just wait until the HR will get in touch with me?

Any advice is much then appreciated.
thank you

Answer (score 1):

**You keep looking for another job**

You have no control over their hiring process; they'll call you when/if they're ready to take the next step.

In the mean time, it's reasonable to be cautiously optimistic (*you did make it past the 1<sup>st</sup> interview*).  However, you should keep looking for other opportunities just in case this doesn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

*They told to wait until this week [...]*

We are **Tuesday**. Technically, they still have three complete business days to come back to you, and they are not late on their timing. Unless you have important information to give them, you do not need to call them before the end of the week.

You should wait at least until Friday afternoon. Monday morning would be my go-to to call them back and ask where is the process standing.